Copy and move file
I have listed of files name in column A, i know the parent(Source) folder, but i don't know which sub-folder have my file. In main folder there is lot of sub folder, so search all sub folder if file name available that file copy and move to destination folder.
Code Explanation: First it ask source folder location destination,  i choose parent folder(parent folder have lot of sub folder)  and then destination folder then it recursively search folder which folder have exact file name if its available any folder it copy and move to destination folder. But this code gone wrong while running.  Please anyone solve this issue.
Sub copy_and_move_selectedfiles_recursive()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sourceFolderDialog As FileDialog
    Dim destinationFolderDialog As FileDialog
    Dim sourceFolderPath As String
    Dim destinationFolderPath As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range
    ' Select source folder
    Set sourceFolderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With sourceFolderDialog
        .Title = "Select Source Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sourceFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    ' Select destination folder
    Set destinationFolderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With destinationFolderDialog
        .Title = "Select Destination Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            destinationFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    ' Initialize FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' Set worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change the sheet name as needed
    ' Find the last row with data in column C
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each cell in column C from C3 to the last row
    For Each c In ws.Range("C3:C" & lastRow)
        ' Search for the file in source folder and its subfolders
        If FileExistsRecursive(sourceFolderPath, c.Value) Then
            ' File exists in source folder or its subfolders
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Moved"
            ' Move the file to destination folder
            FSO.MoveFile sourceFolderPath & c.Value, destinationFolderPath & c.Value
        Else
            ' File not found in source folder or its subfolders
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Not Found"
        End If
    Next c
    ' Clean up
    Set FSO = Nothing
    ' Show completion message
    MsgBox "Process Completed"
End Sub
 
Function FileExistsRecursive(ByVal folderPath As String, ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim found As Boolean
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
    ' Check if the file exists in the current folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFile.Name = fileName Then
            Set FSO = Nothing
            FileExistsRecursive = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next objFile
    ' Recursively search through subfolders
    For Each objFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        If FileExistsRecursive(objFolder.Path, fileName) Then
            Set FSO = Nothing
            FileExistsRecursive = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next objFolder
    ' File not found
    Set FSO = Nothing
    FileExistsRecursive = False
End Function


Please show us the code you have so far and explain how it fails to achieve the desired result. See this question about navigating through sub-directories, which is what I think you want to do.

But this code gone wrong while running.  Pls. tell us in detail how it is gone wrong. Any error message or incorrect result etc.

after running it shows file not found in Column D(status of work), also i check with destination folder there is no file available. Furthermore lastrow taken around 20000 but i give only one number for checking purpose in column C. the file extension is .dxf

Have you tried using debug.print to see what the values of folderPath, objFile.Name, etc... is as you iterate through the directories?

For first sight the found full path is not bubble up from the recursive loop to the FSO.MoveFile method.

Please check my code and kindly rewrite the suitable code.

Try the following changes and take care of the limitations below:
Change in the Sub:
Define a module level variable on the top of the module
Dim foundfile As String
Add this line to the Sub procedure
        If FileExistsRecursive(sourceFolderPath, c.value) Then
            ' File exists in source folder or its subfolders
            c.Offset(0, 1).value = "Moved"
            ' Move the file to destination folder
            FSO.MoveFile foundfile, destinationFolderPath & c.value
            foundfile = ""             '------add this line
        Else
            ' File not found in source folder or its subfolders
            c.Offset(0, 1).value = "Not Found"
        End If


Do the following changes in the Function
Function FileExistsRecursive(ByVal folderPath As String, ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object   '--------------added
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim found As Boolean
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
    ' Check if the file exists in the current folder
    'If InStr(1, folderPath, "appda", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Debug.Print folderPath
    'Debug.Print folderPath
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFile.Name = fileName Then
            Set FSO = Nothing
            foundfile = objFile.Path    '----------------added
            FileExistsRecursive = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next objFile
    ' Recursively search through subfolders
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders   '-----------edited
        'If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Path, "appda", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Stop
        If FileExistsRecursive(objSubFolder.Path, fileName) Then  '------------edited
            Set FSO = Nothing
            FileExistsRecursive = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next objSubFolder         '-------------edited
    ' File not found
    Set FSO = Nothing
    FileExistsRecursive = False
End Function

Limitation: According to MS when using recursive function there is a limited size of variables used in the function. Since it calls the function a not predefined time this issue can occur when there are recursive calls in a higher amount. The outflow of it, is the reason of the malfunctioning of your code. When tested, I also didn't get any error message, the code finished with Moved, but the files remained in their original positions. Probably this means that in a case like this the function returned a false positive result). When I limited the search area the modified code works w/o issue. Limit the search range as narrow as you can or apply some other workaround which reduce the recursive call. More info here from Microsoft.
